# Is there a way to update connection credentials on a sqlalchemy engine?

Tags: sqlalchemy, hashicorp-vault

From what I can tell, the only time sqlalchemy lets you set anything to do with the connection url is when you call `create_engine`.

I'm using [vault's database secret engine](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/databases/index.html) to manage short-lived credentials on the database, which means my application should be robust enough to deal with credential invalidation at any given time.

I'm not looking for how to *catch* the situation of the credentials expiring (that seems straight-forward). What I want is a way to **replace** the connection string (specifically the username and password) used for new connections.

One option I've considered is destroying the engine and recreating a new one, but based on the documentation of [dispose](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html?highlight=dispose#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.dispose), this seems likely to cause memory leaks if there are any connections checked out...

Is there a pattern/recipe people use for this that I just can't seem to find?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've found what I was overlooking: There is a [creator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#custom-dbapi-connect-arguments) callback available on the call to `create_engine` that gives you absolute control over the connection created. You lose the ORM abstraction to the underlying dbapi/dialect but it lets you change the connection however you want.

So my implementation looks something like this:

```
import sqlalchemy
import cx_Oracle

def get_new_connection(self):
    username, password = get_new_creds_from_vault()
    return cx_Oracle.connect(user=username, password=password, dsn='details...')

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('oracle://', creator=get_new_connection)
```

Comment: I know this is quite old question, but can you elaborate on what do you mean by `You lose the ORM abstraction to the underlying dbapi/dialect`?

Comment: I don't remember exactly what I was thinking, so I won't update the answer... Primarily, I expect I meant what the sqlalchemy docs say: `"Usage of this function causes connection parameters specified in the URL argument to be bypassed."`  
I suspect I was unsure what impact changing the connection has on dialect tweaks that might impact the way the ORM acts. For instance, if the default cx_Oracle dialect (which I'm using in my example) relied on a directive sent to oracle immediately after connecting in order to facilitate something to do with joins.
Effects could easily vary by database.